# Why am I getting weired date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime-format

I am using javascript date and I am trying to get it in my own format(YYYY-MM-DD). However, I could manage the format but the problem here is I am getting a day ahead. For eg: if the day is 3(today), here with this code I am getting 4.

```
let currentDate = new Date(currentForm['dobs']);
let middleDate = currentDate.toLocaleDateString().split('-');
let finalDate = middleDate[0] + '-' + middleDate[1] + '-' + (middleDate[2] - 1);
 console.log(finalDate);
```

Here, in `currentDate` I am getting date as: `2051-06-30T18:15:00.000Z`

But, in `finalDate`, I am getting `2049-6-31`

Ignoring the syntax, why am I getting a day ahead ? How to achieve a correct date ??

Comment: It is a day ahead because the original date is in UTC time, and `.toLocaleDateString()` returns a date in your local time zone. This seems like a very shaky approach because `toLocaleDateString()` will return wildly different formats in different locales. Some won't even be formatted in y-M-d format. What is it that you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @JLRishe I am trying to achieve actual date in form 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

Comment: Then you should use `.getYear()` `.getMonth()`, and `.getDate()` and format them yourself. Using `toLocaleDateString` for this is a bad idea. I also suggest that you add your own date parsing or use something like moment.js since using `new Date()` to parse dates is unreliable. However, none of this has anything to do with the issue you're describing. I've already explained why that is happening.

Comment: The format of *toLocaleDateString* is implementation dependent, there's no reason to believe you'll get consistent results, or that the "-" character will appear at all in teh string (it doesn't for me). Your issue is likely because *toLocaleString* is local time, but *currentDate* is UTC. It seems your timezone is +9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to have this question few years ago and the reason is really simple. It's because of the 'Z' character at the end of the date value, because for the .toLocaleDateString() function(given that you haven't specified parameters, here is more [info](https://javascript.info/date#date-parse-from-a-string)) implies this value lies in the UTC+0 zone and for some kind of reason that is always throwing you one day a head.

**Solution:**
To solve this you have many options, but maybe the simplest one is to format the date by yourself like this:

```
function lz(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
var d = new Date('2019-01-01T00:00:00Z');
var formatted = d.getUTCFullYear()+'-'
    + lz(d.getUTCMonth()+1)+'-'
    + lz(d.getUTCDate())+' '
    + lz(d.getUTCHours())+':'
    + lz(d.getUTCMinutes())+':'
    + lz(d.getUTCSeconds());
```

Or you can use third-party libraries like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) which, by the way, is pretty popular. Here is a [link](http://momentjs.com/) for more info.

**Edit:**

My apologies I was omitting one part of my code since I took it directly from one of my projects. Please follow the above code or test it in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hfdkxur1/).

Comment: Where is that 'd' defined ? Do you mean date.getDate() ?? I have tried this too. This also returns a day ahead.

Comment: Even though this will work most of the time, parsing date strings using `new Date()` is [strongly discouraged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: `new Date("2019-01-01 00:00:00")` returns an invalid date in Safari.

Comment: Hi guys, I was missing part of the code, sorry, please follow the edit or go to the fiddler I created. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Alfredo Zamudio answer, I tried to remove that 'Z' attached at the end of my date value and after that everything ok.

```
let currentDate = new Date(currentForm['dobs']);
let newDate = currentDate.toISOString().replace('Z', '');
```

After these lines of code my issue was solved and then I used simple technique to format date.

```
let formattedDate = newDate.getFullYear() + '-' + newDate.getMonth() + '-' + newDate.getDate();
```

Thanks to all !